# Error when compile Spring-Boot app with ant

Tags: java, spring-boot, ant, spring-batch

I am trying to compile a Spring Boot + Batch project with AntLib since in CI Jenkins it is configured this way.

When compiling the project, an error is generated "/ext-lib/spring-boot-antlib-2.4.0.jar!/org/springframework
/boot/ant/antlib.xml:27: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org / springframework / util / StringUtils "

The build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="gprd-logs-cleaner" default="main" basedir="."
    xmlns:au="antlib:org.apache.ant.antunit" 
    xmlns:spring-boot="antlib:org.springframework.boot.ant" 
    xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <property name="src.dir" location="src/main/java" />
    <property name="resource.dir" location="src/main/resources" />
    <property name="target.dir" location="target" />
    <property name="classes.dir" location="${target.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="main-class" value="com.gprd.logs.cleaner.CCCLogsCleanerApp" />

    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
            uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpath="${ivy.class.path}"/>
    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ant/antunit/antlib.xml"
            uri="antlib:org.apache.ant.antunit" classpath="${antunit.class.path}"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/">
            <include name="${lib.dir}/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="setUp">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="setUp">
        <local name="jar" />
        <property name="jar" location="${target.dir}/gprd-logs-cleaner.jar" />
        <spring-boot:exejar destfile="${jar}" classes="${classes.dir}">
            <resources>
                <fileset dir="${resource.dir}" />
            </resources>
            <lib>
                <path refid="classpath" />
            </lib>
        </spring-boot:exejar>
    </target>
    
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${target.dir}" />
    </target>
    
    <!-- Default, run this -->
    <target name="main" depends="clean, compile" />
    
</project>
```

Spring Boot version: **2.3.4.RELEASE**.

I tested with SpringBootAndlib version: **spring-boot-antlib-2.4.4.jar** or **spring-boot-antlib-2.4.0.jar**, the error is the same.

Library list:

```
spring-boot-starter-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar               istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar
spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar                       jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar         spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar       spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar
logback-classic-1.2.3.jar                           spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
logback-core-1.2.3.jar                              slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar
log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar                           spring-aspects-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
log4j-api-2.13.3.jar                                hibernate-entitymanager-5.4.5.Final.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar                             jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar
jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar                    dom4j-2.1.1.jar
spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar                       hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar
spring-jcl-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar                        javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar
snakeyaml-1.26.jar                                  byte-buddy-1.10.14.jar
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar      jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar
spring-boot-starter-aop-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar           spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar                             jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar
spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar          jackson-annotations-2.11.2.jar
HikariCP-3.4.5.jar                                  jackson-core-2.11.2.jar
jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar                   micrometer-core-1.5.5.jar
jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar                   HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar
hibernate-core-5.4.5.Final.jar                      LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar
javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar                             javax.batch-api-1.0.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar                                     jettison-1.2.jar
jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar                              spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
classmate-1.5.1.jar                                 spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar                              spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
txw2-2.3.3.jar                                      spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar                    spring-expression-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar                         spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar                      jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
jasypt-spring-boot-starter-2.0.0.jar                jasypt-spring-boot-2.0.0.jar
jasypt-1.9.2.jar
```

NOTE: We cannot connect to download dependencies.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org / springframework / util / StringUtils "

This error means the class `org.springframework.util.StringUtils` is not found. This class is located in the `spring-core` module.

You have `spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar` in the list you shared, but it does not seem to be in your classpath. You need to make sure that this jar is in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks to reply @Mahmoud but all libraries are into the folder lib.

Comment: the problem may be that it does not correctly resolve the class inside spring-core.
I have put the ```spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar``` library in the same folder as ```spring-boot-antlib-2.4.4.jar``` but it does not resolve it.
Is it likely to be explicitly indicated in the execution of the ant command? If so, please tell me how.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I'm not familiar with ant and how it handles the classpath, but you need to make sure the class is in the classpath to resolve `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: I solved dependency problems with:
```ant -lib ./ext-lib/ -lib ./lib/``` but now I have another error.
```J:\dir\build.xml:45: The following error occurred while executing thi
s line:
jar:file:/J:/dir/./ext-lib/spring-boot-antlib-2.4.4.jar!/org/springfr
amework/boot/ant/antlib.xml:27: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported api 17432576
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved the problem. It already compiles completely, but there are some adjustments to be made.
First you have to indicate where the libraries are by running the command with `ant -debug -lib ./ext-lib/ -lib. /lib/`.
I have extracted from the spring-boot-antlib jar part of the xml and adjusted to my needs.
Here I leave you in case it is useful to someone.

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="gprd-logs-cleaner" default="main" basedir=".">

    <property name="src.dir" location="src/main/java" />
    <property name="resource.dir" location="src/main/resources" />
    <property name="target.dir" location="target" />
    <property name="classes.dir" location="${target.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="main-class" value="com.cleaner.App" />
    <property name="spring-boot.version" value="2.3.4.RELEASE" />
    
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/">
            <include name="${lib.dir}/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Need classpath to run this -->
    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}"
               destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>
    
    <macrodef name="check-exejar" description="Create a spring-boot executable jar">
        <attribute name="destfile" />
        <attribute name="classes" />
        <attribute name="start-class" default="" />
        <attribute name="spring-boot-loader"/>

        <element name="resources" optional="true"
            description="includes resource collections specifying additional Java resources" />

        <element name="lib" optional="true"
            description="includes resource collections containing (jar) dependencies" />

        <sequential>
            <local name="start-class" />

            <echo>Using start class @{start-class}</echo>

            <local name="spring-boot.version" />

            <local name="destdir" />
            <dirname file="@{destfile}" property="destdir" />

            <echo>Using destination directory ${destdir}</echo>
            <mkdir dir="${destdir}/dependency" />

            <echo>Extracting spring-boot-loader to ${destdir}/dependency</echo>
            <local name="spring-boot.loader"/>
            
            <copy todir="${destdir}/dependency">
                <javaresource name="META-INF/loader/spring-boot-loader.jar">
                    <classpath location="@{spring-boot-loader}"/>
                </javaresource>
                <flattenmapper />
            </copy>

            <echo>Embedding spring-boot-loader v2.4.4...</echo>
            <jar destfile="@{destfile}" compress="false">
                <mappedresources>
                    <fileset dir="@{classes}"/>
                    <globmapper from="*" to="BOOT-INF/classes/*" />
                </mappedresources>
                <resources />
                <mappedresources>
                    <lib />
                    <globmapper from="*" to="BOOT-INF/lib/*" />
                </mappedresources>
                <zipfileset src="${destdir}/dependency/spring-boot-loader.jar" />
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class"
                        value="com.cleaner.App" />
                    <attribute name="Start-Class" value="org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher" />
                    <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="gprd-logs-cleaner"/>
                    <attribute name="Spring-Boot-Classes" value="BOOT-INF/classes/" />
                    <attribute name="Spring-Boot-Lib" value="BOOT-INF/lib/" />
                </manifest>
            </jar>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
    
    <target name="build" >
        <local name="jar" />
        <property name="jar" location="${target.dir}/gprd-logs-cleaner.jar" />
        <property name="spring-boot.loader" location="${basedir}/ext-lib/spring-boot-loader-tools-2.4.4.jar" />
        <check-exejar destfile="${jar}" classes="${classes.dir}" spring-boot-loader="${spring-boot.loader}" 
            start-class="com.cleaner.App">
            <resources>
                <fileset dir="${resource.dir}" />
            </resources>
            <lib>
                <path refid="classpath" />
            </lib>
        </check-exejar>
    </target>
    
    <!-- Default, run this -->
    <target name="main" depends="build"/>

</project>
```

I use PropertiesLuncher because I have to extract the properties from the final jar